# Analysis service database backup error - "There are no more files"

Tags: azure-devops, ssas, azure-pipelines, database-backups

I have a azure devops pipeline setup that is to run and backup databases (rdb and analysis db) from server hosting database to a different server with shared location. Everytime i run all the relational Dbs are getting backedup just fine, but it comes to analysis DB it fails on different DB each time but the error is same `**There are no more files**`. Below is the full error stack:

`` Analysis Server Database backup started: db_ModelManager... Error backing up the SSAS database. File system error: The following error occurred during a file operation:  There are no more files. .     at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.AnalysisServicesClient.SendExecuteAndReadResponse(ImpactDetailCollection impacts, Boolean expectEmptyResults, Boolean throwIfError)    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.AnalysisServicesClient.Backup(Database database, String file, Boolean allowOverwrite, Boolean backupRemotePartitions, ICollection locations, Boolean applyCompression, String password)    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Backup(Database database, String file, Boolean allowOverwrite, Boolean backupRemotePartitions, BackupLocation[] locations, Boolean applyCompression, String password)    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Database.Backup(String file, Boolean allowOverwrite)    at BackupandRestoreDBs.Program.BackupASDatabase(String sourceAsDbInstanceName, String targetBackupPath, String targetAsDbInstanceName, List`1 dbNameFilter) in c:\6\_work\22\s\BackupDBSit\Program.cs:line 325 ---> System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Backup of Analysis dbs failed ``

Is this because i am trying to back it up to shared location over network? it runs for around 10 minutes and backs up few databases before failing. I was able to backup databases from a different server without any issues (which ran for couple of minutes) to same location.

Since it is failing on different analysis database i am having hard time figuring out what is causing the same. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did it work fine to backup from local machine [Using SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.mytechmantra.com/sql-server-analysis-services/how-to-backup-analysis-services-database-in-sql-server-using-sql-server-management-studio/) .You can check [this document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/backup-and-restore-of-analysis-services-databases#bkmk_prereq) to make sure the requirements are met, It says restore location must be the same server type, if the Analysis database contains remote partitions, you will have to manually copy those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because one of the database was corrupted causing failure while Backing up the same. After dropping and restoring it from a previous copy the pipelines ran fine and has been running green for few days now.